# apigility how to response from other datas

Tags: php, database, api, laminas-api-tools

I want to create an api. This api should not give back records from database. I do have an application, which does have some logic in it, which does get datas from other apis, does calculate, and much more. 
Is apigility a good start point for it?
Does someone know a tutorial, where I can see more than getting records from database and give it back?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start with Apigility, you can read its documentation at https://apigility.org/documentation. If you want your APIs of high functionality, you can add as much logic as you want. Tutorials won't help in building the logic whereas practice will.

Comment: Yes, apigilty is a great tool for building APIs